# XQUERY 3.0 Multi-level SORT / ORDER BY

Tags: xquery-3.0

I have an XQUERY 3.0 as follows on an XML file with 3 Purchase Order recs with 5 items:

```
 for $PurchaseOrder in doc("C:\Users\thebluephantom\Desktop\order.xml")//PurchaseOrder
   order by xs:integer($PurchaseOrder/Item/Quantity) ascending
   return $PurchaseOrder/Items/Item/Quantity
```

that does not return the results as I want. It has a typical nested structure e.g.

```
<PurchaseOrders>  
  <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">  
    <Address Type="Shipping">  
      <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>  
      ... 
    </Address>  
      <Address Type="Billing">  
        <Name>Tai Yee</Name>  
        <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>  
        ...
    </Address>  
    <DeliveryNotes>Please leave packages in shed by driveway.  </DeliveryNotes>  
    <Items>  
      <Item PartNumber="872-AA">  
      <ProductName>Lawnmower</ProductName>  
      <Quantity>100</Quantity>  
      <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>  
    <Comment>Confirm this is electric</Comment>  
  </Item>  
    <Item PartNumber="926-AA">  
      <ProductName>Baby Monitor</ProductName>  
      <Quantity>20</Quantity>  
      <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>  
      <ShipDate>1999-05-21</ShipDate>  
  </Item>  
</Items>  
 </PurchaseOrder>  
 <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99505" OrderDate="1999-10-22">  
   ...
```

I get the result on 3 POs and 5 Order Items:

```
<Quantity>100</Quantity>
<Quantity>20</Quantity>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Quantity>1000</Quantity>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
```

Looking at a number of tutorials on groupings etc. I am not able to find out if this is in fact possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath in your `Order By` is missing the `Items` axis, so it's selecting nothing and you are getting your results in document order. If you correct the XPath, then there will be a sequence of values selected in the `xs:integer()` invocation and will throw an error.

You could rewrite it like this:

```
for $quantity in 
         doc("C:\Users\thebluephantom\Desktop\order.xml")/PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrder/Items/Item/Quantity
order by xs:integer($quantity) ascending
return $quantity
```

Comment: 1) Unfortunately that does not work, get an optimized Query using BaseX as ()

Comment: 2) xs:integer throw an error --> never came across that in any tutorial

Comment: Whoops, I had been using a local variable to load the content instead of `doc()` and had messed up the XPath. Just added `/PurchaseOrders`

Comment: For clarity: for $quantity in 
         doc("C:\Users\thebluephantom\Desktop\order.xml")//PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrder/Items/Item/Quantity
order by xs:integer($quantity) ascending
return $quantity

Comment: Also, a suitable tutorial is not so easy to find.